# RegExp с несколькими условиями

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

имеются строки

- iPhone 6s 16GB white
- iPhone 5s 16GB black
- iPhone 6s 32GB white
- iPhone 4 16GB white
- iPhone 5s 16GB white

пользователь пишет запрос

> iphone 16gb

Если писать регулярку /^iphone|\siphone|^16gb|\s16gb/ используя `ИЛИ (|)`, то ,результатом будут все строки. Можно ли написать регулярку, чтобы одновременно находило строки, содержащие и iphone, и 16gb, причем порядок слов в запросе пользователя был не важен?

Comment: или проще будет сделать несколько масок, просто комбинируя порядок слов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так: `(?=.*iphone)(?=.*16gb).*`

Comment: А зачем `.*` в конце?

Comment: Вы правы, это лишнее, достаточно `(?=.*iphone)(?=.*16gb)`

Comment: но под предложенную регулярку также попадет строка допустим 
`lalaliphone aa16gb`, как задать так, чтобы именно искомые слова в строке дожны начинаться с iphone и 16gb?

Comment: Используйте границы слов `(?=.*\biphone\b)(?=.*\b16gb\b)`

Comment: @Tunker, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Для решения задачи достаточно использовать круглые скобки для группировки условий:

```
(\s*iPhone.+16GB)|(\s*16GB.+iPhone)
```